# How to perform a significance test for an image classification model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, statistics

I have a created a multi-class classification CNN models using keras,

I have trained my model and generated a classification report on a test set. This yields me evaluation metrics precision, recall and f1 for each model.

Now I would like to know if the respective results for my model are **statistically significant** i.e. determining the **p-value** for the model. How would I test this? Since I can hardly find any example of this being done I wonder if it even makes sense in the context of an image classifier?

Any clarification on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is not much significance testing done in deep learning. You could go for McNemar's test. The problem is that it's expensive to do multiple replications of training and testing with large neural networks. Just a small question, why would you want to compare a multi-class classifier with a multi-label classifier? From the distribution of the labels, only one of both can be the 'correct' model to use, right? If you're in a multi-label situation, the multi-class classifier should really underperform.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "there is not much significance testing done in deep learning"? Are there any alternatives to McNemar's test? Regarding your question: I do not want to compare both models with each other. I merely want to check the significance for each model independently from each other. Sorry if that was not clear from my description above.

Comment: In machine learning, significance testing is largely 'replaced' by using train-test splitting. I'm not sure what you mean with the significance of a single model. You could calculate the AUC of both models to compare them to random classifiers (AUC of 0.5 = no better than a random classifier). McNemar's test is intended to compare two models with eachother.

Comment: With "significance of a model" I mean that I want to check for each model whether my values for precision, recall and f1 score are statistically significant. Thank you for the advice with AUC, I will look into that!

Comment: I guess with that, you mean that they are statistically significant from the precision, recall and f1 score from a random classifier. In that case, you really want to read up on the AUC. It's not a traditional statistical test, but it does incorporate precision and recall.

Comment: @AaronDT significance tests aren't meaningful in this context. You can conclude a priori that the two models are different; there isn't anything further to conclude from a significance test. My advice is to quantify the difference in a way that is meaningful for the purpose for which you propose to use a classification model.

Comment: Robert i don't want to compare both models. I want to test the significance of each model separately. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Aaron, "test the significance of each model" -- I'm not sure this is meaningful. I suppose this must mean comparing each model to a base model and seeing if the difference in some measurement (AUC, f1, etc) is "significant". But the base model is not uniquely defined, and you can define it to be much less accurate or approximately as accurate (or even more accurate) than the model you're testing. So you can get a range of differences, and if you're looking for one result or another you can get whatever you want. This is in addition to the general problems with statistical significance.

Comment: Okay, so do I understand you correctly, that for example in a regression scenario I can test for significance since I am able assume the "base model" follows a normal distribution but with a classifier I cannot conclude a similar assumption? And this means there is no correct way of telling whether the results of the classifier are significant i.e. not due to chance?